# Referencing Instantiated objects after their creation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hi!**

After the discussion with Ruzihm in the comments. I've now created a simple version of my game to better ask the question I'm having.

The question now is, since I'm not able to manually create a connection to the `testObject` field in the inspector. How do I now tell Unity to use my instantiated objects while the game is running?

And is this a good solution for a RTS game that may have 100s of Units active at a time? The end goal here is to apply this force to a radius around the cursor. Which I was thinking of using `Physics.OverlapSphere`

**Here's the minimal scenario of what I have:**

1. New Unity scene
2. Attached the InputManager to the main camera.
3. Created a capsule and a plane.
4. Added ApplyForce to the Capsule
5. Created a prefab from the capsule and deleted it from the scene.
6. In the InputManager I added the ability to press space to Instantiate a capsule with the ApplyForce script attached..
7. Drag the capsule prefab to the InputManager "objectToGenerate"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace GL.RTS.Mites
{
    public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject testObject;

        public ApplyForce onSpawnTest;
        public GameObject objectToGenerate;

        void Start()
        {
            onSpawnTest = testObject.GetComponent<ApplyForce>();
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
            Instantiate(objectToGenerate);
            }
            
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                onSpawnTest.PushForward();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ApplyForce script that I attach to the Capsule:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace GL.RTS.Mites
{
    public class ApplyForce : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float moveSpeed;
        Rigidbody rb;

        void Start()
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            Debug.Log("A Mite has spawned!");
        }

        public void PushForward()
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log("A force of: " + moveSpeed + " is being added.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which programming language is this code?: C# or UnityScript? It looks like C# to me but you've tagged both.

Comment: This is c#, sorry I'll remove the UnityScript tag

Comment: Is the object you want to move part of the initial scene or it is spawned at a later point? If at a later point then `InputManager.Start` method may be running before the spawning object is instantiated.

Comment: It's spawned as soon as the scene is played. I got a unitManager as well where I have the following code.

`GameObject unit = Instantiate(_unit.unitPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, basic);`

That's a good point, I guess if the InputManager runs before the object has been spawned it could cause some issues?

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The problem is that for some reason when I try to use `rb.AddRelativeForce()` from a different script, it's not moving. Even though moving the same line to a void update() on the object it starts moving.

I get no errors from the code, I have another script attached as a test where I use a force of 300 which feels good for the objects. 

Another thing I've considered trying is having the forces be "always on" so to speak, and then feed the speed from the Input Manager script instead.

Comment: Works for me, I can't reproduce the problem of the object not moving. please include a [mre]. For unity questions, this includes steps to set up the scene, what gameobjects to include, what components to attach to them, etc. It would also help if your code matched your description, such as including the `Instantiate` call mentioned in the description.

Comment: To reproduce success from new scene - create capsule, attach rigidbody, set mass to 0.1, attach `ApplyForce`, set `moveSpeed` to 300.  Create plane, move under capsule. Add `InputManager` to camera. Remove undefined `_unit` field. assign capsule to `testObject`. Enter play mode. Press left mouse button. Observe capsule lift from plane.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Let me give this a try today and I'll update my questions once I've got a basic scenario ready :) I love the way you phrased `Observe capsule lift from plane`. It will be a miracle for sure!

Comment: You are correct @Ruzihm, I tried to create a completely new Unity scene, attached the InputManager to the main camera. Created a capsule and a plane. Added ApplyForce to the capsule, and referenced the capsule to the InputManager's "testObject" in the inspector. Added a ton of force and I it did start to fly! This is great cause then I know it's not a problem with the code! 

My issue is then is that the "testObject" in my "real" Unity scene is not correctly referencing the instance. So I need to figure out how to reference the instance after it has been created.

Comment: I'm glad you found the same result as me. If you edit the question to reproduce your original problem, please @ me again and I'll take another look

Comment: Really appreciate your help! I'll be updating this thread asap :)

Comment: @Ruzihm, I finally had the time to update the question to better reflect my issue. I think I know what I'm trying to do in the code, but with my limited experience in C# I'm unable to reference the correct object to add force to. Any help would be awesome! I'm also open to suggestions, as I don't know if this method will scale well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are creating your new instances of your object, but your input manager immediately forgets about them (note that you do nothing with the return value). The `InputManager` only knows about the `ApplyForce` that was created in its `Start` (and then interacts with it depending on mouse input) and your `ApplyForce` script knows nothing about any `InputManager`. So, it should come as no surprise that only the first instance reacts to the mouse input.

So, something has to be done to your `InputManager` and/or your `ApplyForce`. Your `InputManager` could remember the instances it creates (which isn't enough, because what if for example, a map trigger creates new player controllable units) or it could go looking for units each time.

Your `ApplyForce` could register with the `InputManager` when they are created, but then you would need to loop through the units and find out which ones are under the mouse, anyway.

Since you only want to select ones based on what is near or under your cursor and only when input occurs and not like every frame, I would go with the simplest approach, just letting your `InputManager` find the units when it needs them. Something like below, explanation in comments:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace GL.RTS.Mites
{
    public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject testObject;

        public ApplyForce onSpawnTest;
        public GameObject objectToGenerate;
        
        private Camera mainCam;

        // which layers to consider for cursor detection
        [SerializeField] LayerMask cursorLayerMask;

        // how big for cursor detection
        [SerializeField] float cursorRadius;

        void Awake()
        {
            // cache main camera
            mainCam = Camera.main;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Instantiate(objectToGenerate);
            }
            
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                Collider[] colls = FindCollidersUnderCursor();

                // check each collider for an applyforce and use it if present
                foreach( Collider coll in colls)
                {
                    ApplyForce af = coll.GetComponent<ApplyForce>();
                    if (af != null) 
                    {
                        af.PushForward();
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        Collider[] FindCollidersUnderCursor()
        {
            // find ray represented by cursor position on screen
            // and find where it intersects with ground

            // This technique is great for if your camera can change
            // angle or distance from the playing field.

            // It uses mathematical rays and plane, no physics
            // calculations needed for this step. Very performant.
            Ray cursorRay = mainCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
            if (groundPlane.Raycast(cursorRay, out float cursorDist))
            {
                Vector3 worldPos = cursorRay.GetPoint(cursorDist);

                // Check for triggers inside sphere that match layer mask
                return Physics.OverlapSphere(worldPos, cursorRadius, 
                        cursorLayerMask.value, QueryTriggerInteraction.Collide);
            }

            // if doesn't intersect with ground, return nothing
            return new Collider[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this will require that every unit you're interested in manipulating has a trigger collider.

Comment: I would upvote but I'm 2 points away from doing so. I'll come back when I have the privilege!

Anyway, thanks a million! This gives me plenty to work with. I know my question was messy, but I've learned a ton from narrowing it down like this. The Collider trick is awesome! I love the idea of creating a virtual ground for your ray to hit. And your implementation of the OverlapSphere as a nice bonus, this is finally making sense.