# Unity For loop inside of OnTriggerEnter2D causes sometimes multiple outcomes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i am new to unity and programing in general so sorry if this is stupid question i am sure there are better ways to do this. Basicly i followed tutorial for inventory with draggable components and now i am implenting his methods to pick up items in my game. I tagged each item with his id. Tags are Item_0, Item_1, Item_2, etc.... and i am using for loop inside of OnTriggerEnter2D to determinate which item i picking up.

There is code for inventory:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> CharacterItmes = new List<Item>();
    public ItemDatabase itemDatabase;
    public UIInventory inventoryUI;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject inventory;

    private void Start()
    {
        inventoryUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     // Iniciate Items
        inventoryUI.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Inventory"))
        {

            inventoryUI.gameObject.SetActive(!inventoryUI.gameObject.activeSelf);
        }
    }
    public void GiveItem(int id)
    {
        Item itemToAdd = itemDatabase.GetItem(id);
        CharacterItmes.Add(itemToAdd);
        inventoryUI.AddNewItem(itemToAdd);
       // Debug.Log("Added item: " + itemToAdd.title);
    }

    public void GiveItem(string itemName)
    {
        Item itemToAdd = itemDatabase.GetItem(itemName);
        CharacterItmes.Add(itemToAdd);
        inventoryUI.AddNewItem(itemToAdd);
       // Debug.Log("Added item: " + itemToAdd.title);
    }

    public Item CheckForItem(int id)
    {
        return CharacterItmes.Find(item => item.id == id);       
    }

    public void RemoveItem(int id)
    {
        Item itemToRemove = CheckForItem(id);
        if (itemToRemove != null)
        {
            CharacterItmes.Remove(itemToRemove);
            inventoryUI.RemoveItem(itemToRemove);
           // Debug.Log("Removed Item: " + itemToRemove.title);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {

            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Item_" + i.ToString()))
            {
                GiveItem(i);
                Debug.Log("Item_" + i.ToString());
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
            }
        }

        

    }
}
```

I have just 6 items for testing purposis right now latter i will replace lenght in for loop with variable with all items in ItemDatabase.

I have tagged all items with right tags and i was checking twice that my character has only 1 Collider2D and rigidbody so as all my items. Only 1 Collider2D set up as Trigger. So i have no clue why i sometimes pick up this items twice:

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI5EZ.jpg)

Any ideas why it picking up multiple times or some better ways how to handle picking up itmes???
I will be glad for any advice. Thanks a lot

Comment: what happens when you rerun and try again? Is it specifically Item_4 that is appearing twice or does it vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a tag for every item you have, especially if it means you will have to loop through many items every time something is dragged over your inventory. It's unnecessary computation and could slow down your game if you have many kinds of items.

Instead, attach a simple mb to each item:

```
public class Pickupable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int itemId;
}
```

Then in `OnTriggerEnter2D`, check if the trigger's attached to such a mb, and get the id from it if so:

```
Pickupable p = other.GetComponent<Pickupable>();
if (p != null)
{
    int id = p.itemId; 
    GiveItem(id);
    Debug.Log($"Item_{id}"); // format string is easier to read
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot this is much smarter solution, but it didnt solve my problem i still picking up multiple items so problem wasn't in for loop but somewhere else. 

https://imgur.com/NMWFdip

Anyway Thx a lot for better solution.

I unchecked Tags, and item have only 1 Collider2D with trigger checked and Pickupable script with ID

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than what's mentioned in the question. If you'd like to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [mre], including how to set up the scene from scratch, what gameobjects to include, and components to attach to reproduce the problem, someone can certainly help you. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70387979/1092820) for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid. I indeed had multiple box colliders on my character. Only thing was that he was hidden in children GameObject and was providing functionality to other game mechanic so i deleted that BoxCollider and figured out that mechanic in other way. Now everything works clearly :)

**So if anybody had similiar problem always make sure that you have Only 1 BoxCollider. On Object and Character as well**