# FindObjectOfType<Present>() Returns Null. Why is this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

(Yeah, I know it says this is a duplicate. I also know what this error means. I'm trying to figure out why the present variable is null)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Score.Update ()

Getting an error with this script. Apparently the present variable is null, and I'm trying to figure out why.

Here's my Score script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshPro scoreText;
    public Present present;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        present = FindObjectOfType<Present>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = present.score.ToString();
    }
}
```

And here's my Present script(script with the score variable):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Present : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 velocity;
    private double deletionZone = 15;
    public int score = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // move to the left
        transform.Translate(velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        if (transform.position.x <= -deletionZone)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            score += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) use the debugger or other means to figure out which variable is null. 2) backtrack to figure out _why_ it's null. If you figure out _what_ is null but don't know _why_, the edit your question and maybe it will get reopened.

Comment: Change the wording to *"FindObjectOfType<Present>() retuns null and I dont understand why"* will likey get your question reopened. Get rid of the exception parts in the question and focus on how you checked that the variable was null and why you expect it to not be null.

Comment: You really need to do some basic debugging first. You haven't even said which line you are getting this error on, although I can guess. And you state *"Start is called before the first frame update"* without backing that up: have you set breakpoints to confirm that?

Comment: No mention is made of creating a `Present` component and/or attaching one to any gameobject in scene. Consider doing that or editing the question to include a [mre].

Comment: Are you sure the object with the present script is made when this code runs

Comment: `I'm trying to figure out why the present variable is null)` -> [Debugging your code in Unity and your external IDE](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

Comment: See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70387979/1092820) for an example of a [mre].

Comment: At the very least you should put in some Debug.Log("Present is Awake"); etc. in the awake and start methods of your classes. Comment out your find object and run the code with these to try and get of sense of what is happening when, this will help inform you whether or not your Present object is even created when you are trying to call the find.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem a few days ago, but didn't update it here.

Apparently FindObjectOfType() actually didn't return null, I guess I made assumptions before debugging and posting this.

Anyways,

---

Instead of using

```
public TextMeshPro scoreText;
```

This is what I should've done:

```
public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
```

Could've saved me a day of working on my game jam project :|

Comment: This answer would be improved if it explained how it makes `pesent` non-null

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I think its because you are naming the Present field with upper case P, it should be lowee case - present.
So public Present present;

Comment: Did that, still getting an error.

Comment: Have you attached the Present Component to a gameobject and attached it in the inspector?

Comment: Yeah, done that. Still have the problem.

Comment: In the above code the present field is set as private, did you change to public or [SerializeField] to be able to attach a gameobject?

Comment: Yeah I did, I didn't edit the script here. I'll do that now.