# My spawning in script is not working and I am unsure as to why this is happening

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

How my spawning in script should work is there is a large cube (250 by 250 by 250) and it has a box collider with the trigger enabled. Each mob has a value which is their health/10. My goal is to make it so that each area has a value of 100 and if it has less than that it will randomly spawn in a new mob until it goes back to 100 value. I am getting an error on the line that I am instantiating the mob on that it is giving a null reference exception error. I have assigned the enemy gameobjects in the instpector. I am purposfully not spawning in the spiders because I am doing something special for them. If there is any code you need just comment and I should be able to give it to you. Thank you

Edit: I also got an null reference exception error on start on the line where I am adding the Alk to the Enemies list

Edit: In this scene there are no other objects that would interfere with the spawning in because I disabled all of the other objects one by one and I got no errors. All of the values in the enemy base script that are related to this have values that have been assigned to them. I hope that helps narrow it down

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnInScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class EnemyWorth
    {
        public float health;
        public int weight;
        public GameObject self;

        public EnemyWorth(float health, int weight, GameObject self)
        {
            this.health = health;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.self = self;            
        }
    }

    public GameObject Alk;
    public GameObject GoblinSpawn;
    public GameObject Goblin;
    public GameObject Cobra;
    public GameObject Spider;
    public GameObject SpiderMini;

    [SerializeField]
    public EnemyWorth[] Enemies;

    public int areaWorth;

    private int rand;

    private float randX;
    private float randY;
    private float randZ;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {       
        Enemies[0] = new EnemyWorth (Alk.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().health, Alk.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().worth, Alk);
        Enemies[1] = new EnemyWorth (GoblinSpawn.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().health, GoblinSpawn.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().worth, GoblinSpawn);
        Enemies[2] = new EnemyWorth (Goblin.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().health, Goblin.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().worth, Goblin);
        Enemies[3] = new EnemyWorth (Cobra.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().health, Cobra.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().worth, Cobra);
        Enemies[4] = new EnemyWorth (Spider.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().health, Spider.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().worth, Spider);
        Enemies[5] = new EnemyWorth (SpiderMini.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().health, SpiderMini.GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().worth, SpiderMini);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (areaWorth > 100)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (areaWorth < 100)
        {
            rand = Random.Range(0, 3);
            randX = Random.Range(-125, 125);
            randY = Random.Range(-125, 125);
            randZ = Random.Range(-125, 125);

            Instantiate(Enemies[rand].self, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x -randX, this.transform.position.y - randY, this.transform.position.z - randZ), Quaternion.identity); // I am getting an error on this line
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject == Enemies[0].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[0].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[1].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[1].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[2].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[2].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[3].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[3].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[4].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[4].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[5].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[5].weight;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject == Enemies[0].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[0].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[1].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[1].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[2].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[2].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[3].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[3].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[4].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[4].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == Enemies[5].self)
        {
            areaWorth += Enemies[5].weight;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like one or more of `Alk`, `GoblinSpawn`, or `Goblin` are unassigned in the inspector.

Comment: I have assigned them all in the inspector I can show a screenshot @Ruzihm

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, otherwise the nullreferenceexception would occur in Start. I can't reproduce this problem from the information in the question - Please include a [mre]. For unity questions this includes steps to recreate the problem starting from a fresh project, including how to set up the scene, attach components, etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70387979/1092820) for a good example.  An alternative is to describe more of what is happening in your current case - are there other active monobehaviors? does the problem stop when they are removed? etc

Comment: @Ruzihm I added some more edits to help narrow down the answer but to my knowledge there are no other monobehaviors interfering with this

Comment: I recommend trying to create a new scene and reproducing this problem step by step and seeing when it reappears. My only guess is that there could be another instance of SpawnInScript that isnt configured properly. There really isn't more that can be said without a [mre].  Also it is very disappointing that the other NRE wasnt mentioned for some reason until the possibility of it was mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question it should have no more code than the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem by copy-pasting, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that when enemies were spawning in the area value wouldnt go back up becuase there wasnt anything adding to the value when they spawned in. I also optimized the code a bit more.

I was able to fix it by doing this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnInScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class EnemyWorth
    {        
        public int weight;
        public GameObject self;

        public EnemyWorth(int weight, GameObject self)
        {            
            this.weight = weight;
            this.self = self;            
        }
    }

    public GameObject[] monsters;

    public EnemyWorth[] enemies = new EnemyWorth[6];

    public int maxAreaWorth;

    public float dimX;
    public float dimY;
    public float dimZ;


    [SerializeField]
    private int areaWorth;

    private int rand;

    private float randX;
    private float randY;
    private float randZ;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < monsters.Length; i++)
        {
            enemies[i] = new EnemyWorth(monsters[i].GetComponent<EnemyBaseScript>().worth, monsters[i]);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (areaWorth < maxAreaWorth)
        {
            rand = Random.Range(0, 3);
            randX = Random.Range(-dimX, dimX);
            randY = Random.Range(-dimY, dimY);
            randZ = Random.Range(-dimZ, dimZ);

            Instantiate(enemies[rand].self, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x -randX, this.transform.position.y - randY, this.transform.position.z - randZ), Quaternion.identity);
            areaWorth += enemies[rand].weight;
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject == enemies[0].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[0].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[1].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[1].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[2].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[2].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[3].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[3].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[4].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[4].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[5].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[5].weight;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject == enemies[0].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[0].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[1].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[1].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[2].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[2].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[3].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[3].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[4].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[4].weight;
        }
        else if (col.gameObject == enemies[5].self)
        {
            areaWorth += enemies[5].weight;
        }
    }
}
```