# When running script on Camera.main play doesn't update scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have the following scene that appears in game mode and in my scene mode.
[image]

I attempt to add some movement with a mouse in a script with the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // horizontal rotation speed
    public float horizontalSpeed = 1f;
    // vertical rotation speed
    public float verticalSpeed = 1f;
    private float xRotation = 0.0f;
    private float yRotation = 0.0f;
    private Camera cam;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalSpeed;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * verticalSpeed;

        yRotation += mouseX;
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);
// this is for the mouse to move around the scene
        cam.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, yRotation, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

It works fine.  It's important to note the camera Main Camera displays the image above.
So it looks right.

Here is what the play view looks like when cam.transform.eulerAngles is not commented out.  When it's commented out it appears exactly as the first reference which is correct.  Any idea what's causing this?

[image]

Comment: Please include enough information to reproduce the described behavior starting from an empty scene, including how to populate the scene with gameobjects, assign components, etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70387979/1092820) for a good example. Also, the above code does not compile because `xRotation` and `yRotation` are undefined. See [mre] for more info and consider reading [ask].

Comment: It would also help improve the question if you were to explain what the line `cam.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, yRotation, 0.0f);` is expected to do, or rather why it would be expected to do the same thing as not including that line.

Comment: Ok I added the purpose it's to move around with the mouse.  @Ruzihm

Comment: This is not a question , which can be answered directly by the way it has been asked. Include some code which can let us know what exactly causes the problem .

Comment: I have included the full code now @Mihaylov

Comment: I can't be sure because the question is incomplete (see [mre]) but my best guess is that it's because your main camera transform is not configured with (0,0,0) rotation in the scene. It may fix your problem if you initialize your `xRotation` and `yRotation` suitably: `void Start() { cam = Camera.main; Vector3 camEulers = cam.transform.eulerAngles; xRotation = camEulers.x; yRotation = camEulers.y; }`

Comment: That worked! @Ruzihm. Can you give an explanation as to WHY it worked?

Comment: @Ruzihm also if you just want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera's rotation has some nonzero value assigned in your scene. So, when `xRotation` and `yRotation` are initialized with zeros, the offending line `cam.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, yRotation, 0.0f);` overwrites the scene-defined rotation with zeros, aka, the "identity rotation".

To avoid this, have your code read what your camera's rotation is at the start and use those values instead of zeros:

```
void Start()
{
    cam = Camera.main;

    Vector3 camEulers = cam.transform.eulerAngles;
    xRotation = camEulers.x;
    yRotation = camEulers.y;
}
```