# Unity3D OnTriggerEnter2D is never called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupCoin : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Coin was picked up");
        }
    }
}
```

Script is assigned to randomly spawned sprites, but player cannot interact with them, and Debug is never called. This means method is never called for reasons unknown to me.

If you need additional info I can provide it.

Comment: Code works for me. Please edit the question to include a [mre]. For unity questions this includes enough information starting from a new project including how to populate the scene, assign values in the inspector, etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70387979/1092820) for a good example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, just check if the player and the created sprites have a Box Collider component.