# Playing scene selecting background instead of button?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to select this buttons clicking in Ch.1 as Chapter 1.

[image]

And as you can see in the image, when I click the buttons, it will just select the objects in that area except the buttons:

[image]

Clicking again chapter 1:

[image]

For me it's a surprise that when the tablet gets selected I see the object is not even the pdf viewer, it's just a decoration.

[image]

Here are the layers:

[image]

[image]

Buttons are configured as layer UI:

[image]

I've tested to change the layer UI to teleport to see if it's a layer level problem but didn't make any difference.

Please let me know if there is any information missing in this question, I'm very new to Unity3d.

Why is mouse selecting those items instead of clicking the buttons?

Comment: you're in the Scene tab, maybe you mean to be clicking in the Game tab instead?

Comment: in the game tab I just don't see the tablet and in the scene tab it was working when I first got this files but I don't have them anymore, I might be able to make it work again in the scene tab

Comment: Interesting. Debugging questions on stack overflow need a [mre]. Please include one for this problem in the question. For Unity questions this includes necessary scripts as well as how to set up the scene, assign components, configure the components, etc starting from a blank project. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70387979/1092820) for a good example.